# Delete entire word with single back space in edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, tagging

I have one requirement. Have one `editText` and I can able to add the data from `recyclerView` to `editText`. And if we click on back `button` entire word should delete and again can able to add any item from `recyclerView` at any position. And need to save the added items in one list. (Simply its like facebook tagging.. In facebook we can tag any friend from list popup and can edit in middle and can delete from middle and can add in middle of that `editText`. My requirement is exactly like that. I want exactly like facebook tagging including editing post). Can any one please help me out of this. I have no idea about this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On back pressed edittext.setText("");

Comment: no I  dont want entire text only a particular value which is added from popup recycler.

Comment: Post sample snippet will great to help

Comment: I have no idea  how to do that

Comment: while pressing back button check if the editext has some word or not. if the edittext has some word just set the edittextField value to "".

Comment: have you found out a solution?

Comment: Yes. I found solution for that

Answer (score 0):

It is [MultiAutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html)

```
<MultiAutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:hint="In areas (comma separated)"
                    android:popupBackground="@color/white"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color" />
```

**You need set adapter for opening listview**

```
search_text = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    FilterWithSpaceAdapter<String> filterWithSpaceAdapter=new FilterWithSpaceAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.checked_textview, R.id.text1, autoSearchLists);

                search_text.setAdapter(filterWithSpaceAdapter);
                search_text.setThreshold(1);
                search_text.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
```

Comment: cant we replace comma separation with space?

Comment: No that link ... comma separator with space

Comment: search_text.setTokenier(new SpaceTokenizer());  use this